# Eta conversion tactics?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a tactic which I can use instead of `replace` in the example below to simplify this expression?

```
Require Import Vector.

Goal forall (n b:nat) (x:t nat n), (map (fun a => plus b a) x) = x.
Proof.
  intros n b x.
  replace (fun a => plus b a) with (plus b) by auto.
  ...
```

Comment: I am afraid that `fun a => plus b a = plus a` indeed holds by conversion, so I'd say replace is the proper one; of course you could use some LTAC. The interesting question here is why do you want to do the replace in the first place?

Comment: I have complex expressions with many functions like this which makes them hard to read. I would love to simplify them a bit by getting rid of all unnecessary lambdas.

Comment: `change (fun a => plus b a) with (plus b).` is a bit simpler.

Comment: Yeah you may define a tactic to clean your expressions up, as long as they are convertible that will be relatively cheap; a better idea may be to control unfolding of your definitions so you can avoid the "ugliness" to be created in the first place. You may try to use arguments or tricks such as ssr's `nosimpl`, YMMV.

Comment: I am not very experienced with LTAC. Is it possible to write such general-purpose tactic in LTAC, which handles arbitrary functions? Can somebody sketch some initial LTAC code for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along the following lines:

```
repeat change (fun x => ?h x) with h.
```

which allows you to eta-reduce functions of *arbitrary* arity. This solution uses `change`'s ability to work with patterns (`?h` in the above piece of code).

Let's give this tactic a more suggestive name like so:

```
(* h is a dummy argument to make Coq happy, it gets shadowed with `?h` *)
Ltac eta_reduce_all_private h := repeat change (fun x => ?h x) with h.

Ltac eta_reduce_all := eta_reduce_all_private idtac.
```

If we try to define `eta_reduce_all` as follows

```
Ltac eta_reduce_all := repeat change (fun x => ?h x) with h.
```

Coq will complain about "unbounded" `h`.

Comment: cool! If there is a way to generalize it to an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: @krokodil I've updated the answer with a hack. Not really a solution for an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @krokodil I updated the answer. Could you please check if the new solution works for your use case?